# How to remove bold font for file path in modified .bash_profile?

Tags: bash

I was looking up a few things to modify my bash terminal on my Mac to have a bit more color when doing ls and things.

I pretty much found what I've needed but haven't been able to figure out one thing.

When I cd to a different directory, the file path it shows is in bold yellow font. I would rather have it in standard weight font, instead of bold.

I've tried to edit a few things on the line, but I don't exactly know which part is making it bold. I've been trying to edit a few things, but each time I mess up something else. I figured I'd leave it to the experts that actually know what each part of the command is doing, rather than me keep hacking away until I get lucky.

Here is my .bash_profile and a picture of my terminal output. I want /Documents to have standard weight yellow instead of bold.

Excuse some the stuff that is commented out. I've been experimenting with what I want.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bold is caused by the **`;1`**. 
To remove it, change `33;1m` to `33m`. 
However, if it turns brown, it doesn’t mean that you (or I) messed up;
it means that may be the best you’re going to get. 
Traditionally, yellow = brown + bold;
i.e., there is no such thing as non-bold yellow.

Comment: Thanks! I changed it to `33m` which gave it a bit of a gold looking color. Changing it again to `93m` gave it more of a yellow color.